# Photo file naming pattern of Mac Photos App - How to get the photos with portrait effect?

Tags: iphone, finder, photos, heic

I am struggling with the new file naming structure of mac.. I have lastly updated my mac to Catalina, but i am not sure if this change was made before Catalina.

Unfortunately i have been manually exporting my photos from the photos app (from the masters folder), and now i realize that, all these photos (original files, .heic) do not have the iphone blur effect.  So i go back to photos app, the photos are still listed there, but i cannot export them since the originals are missing. And i am also not able to put those originals back, since the photos app works suddenly with another file naming strategy. originals folder, instead of master.. and also all the originals called like B6EFD48D-315A-4A40-A17F-CA1C2D69E8CD_5.

Is there any way to find out how apple produce this name? I would like to create this name from the original file name "IMG_6883.heic". So i can put those originals back and export files jpeg files with the edited (blurry) version.

**The problem in other words:**

- I have my original iphone photos (without portrait effect) in a local folder, they are called like IMG_6877.heic
- Photos app does still shows the portrait version of those photos. But i cannot reach to them in the finder's file system (export also does not work), or they just do not exist since the original file is missing.

Comment: Did you *export* the photos with the functionality within Photos or did you move the files out of the Originals folders directly in Finder?

Comment: i moved them out of the originals..

Comment: Well, this will be tricky then. No photo management applications don't react well if you kind of pull the carpet out under them.

Comment: no photo management app constantly tries to hide the actual files from the user! It is called "transparency" and "user-friendly" in software-world.

Comment: Photos has export abilities etc, there is no need to access the photos directly on disk.

Comment: oh god.. again this discussion.. it is very clear that you are an apple fan. but actually, it is the software which should adapt itself to people. not the reverse. and for years, the people are working with the normal filesystem, where they also can see the actual files. so it is very "nature". but still, have fun in your apple addicted world. i know, whatever i say, you will "defend" apple. just continue.